# hardware fan is accelerating too often

Tags: hardware-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fan is accelerating too often.](https://superuser.com/questions/281587/fan-is-accelerating-too-often)

Hi everyone,

I have just applied thermal paste to my intel quadcore CPU and the fan seems to be accelerating very often. Especially after I installed a new graphics card. I suspect my CPU may be overheating. There is supposed to be this "break-in" period the thermal paste. I used artic silver 5 and it says that the break-in period is 200 hours. I don't quite understand, what I am supposed to do during this break-in period.

It seems like I just have to wait, but as far as I understand I can still use the computer. Also, does this mean that the fan accelerating so often is a symptom of this break-in period? or is something wrong?

Any help appreciated,

Ted